# Separating Values from a String in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string comma separated where I want to get 2 values in variables. How can I accomplish it.

```
$responseData = "Data: invoice=1216,card=AMEX";
```

I am looking for value of Invoice and Card.

I tried using instring but not getting value I want.

Comment: *I tried* Show us your attempt and your effort!

Comment: Looks like a prima facie case for [sscanf()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php): `list($invoice, $card) = sscanf($responseData, "Data: invoice=%d,card=%s");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## sscanf()

You can use [`sscanf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) to achieve this result.

`sscanf()` takes the same format as `printf()`, allowing you to provide a variable and expected format string, and will return the matching results.

[For example](https://eval.in/315607):

```
list($invoice, $card) = sscanf($responseData, "Data: invoice=%d,card=%s");
var_dump($invoice); // int(1216)
var_dump($card);    // string(4) "AMEX"
```

*Community wiki of Mark Baker's answer in the comments above.*

## explode()

You can also do this manually by breaking up the string by delimiters with [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode). The `Data:` component is irrelevant, so trim it off, then split by commas, then split by `=` to get a key => value pair.

[For example](https://eval.in/315609):

```
// Remove the Data: component
$responseData = ltrim($responseData, 'Data: ');

$example = array();
// Split by commas
foreach (explode(',', $responseData) as $value) {
    // Split by equals
    list ($k, $v) = explode('=', $value);
    $example[$k] = $v;
}

var_dump($example);
// array(2) {
//   ["invoice"]=>
//   string(4) "1216"
//   ["card"]=>
//   string(4) "AMEX"
// }
```

Answer (score 2):

## preg_match()

Here is the **[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)** version using named subpatterns:

```
$subject = 'Data: invoice=1216,card=AMEX';

$matches = [];

preg_match('/Data: invoice=(?<invoice>\d+),card=(?<card>\w+)/', $subject, $matches);

var_dump($matches['invoice']); // string(4) "1216"
var_dump($matches['card']);    // string(4) "AMEX"
```